# UI button doesn't show up in Unity's gameview

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, augmented-reality

For context: I am building an AR experience in Unity (with the AR setup) as the android counterpart to the adobe aero experience (completed). I've been following a bunch of tutorials for implementing buttons that switch between scenes, and have since abandoned the little 3D slab button I created in blender, instead using the UI button from unity as suggested by the tutorials. Problem is, it is now the only object that doesn't appear when I go into gameview, meaning that I can't test if it works after I've applied the functional C# script to it.

I've tried disabling and enabling several settings in both the AR camera and the button's inspectors, to no avail. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome. [image: The scene showing the camera view]

Comment: If you want to receive help with this you need to describe how you added the button. 
A screenshot of your scene view does nothing for this.
For example what kind of canvas is it on, screen-space or world-space? Your "Next arrow" seems to show up fine, so maybe look at that and replicate how you set it up.

Comment: Check your canvas settings. It is responsible for rendering ui elements like the unity button.

Comment: It looks like you have positioned the UI in worldspace rather than positioning it correctly on the canvas, unless that is what you're going for? It would be helpful to see canvas settings, and the settings for the UI element(s) that aren't working. What does the UI look like in the `Game` view rather than the `Scene` view? If the UI is set up correct, you should be able to see it there and not on the `AR Camera` viewport.

Comment: Looks like it's placed on a Canvas for Overlay, but Render Mode is set to World Space, or perhaps it's set to Screen Space-Camera and the camera has not been assigned, so the Canvas defaults to a sort of World Space like mode.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your replies, it has been most helpful. Based on your suggestions I have discovered that my canvas was set to screen space and not world space, and it now shows up in gameview.